# Error when trying to connect & run query: Message 0085E084 SQLSTATE 0085E88C

Tags: c++, azure-sql-database

I have been trying to connect to Azure SQL and query from it.

I get this error message:

[image: Error Image while debug]

Here is the complete code that I have used:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>

using namespace std;

void show_error(unsigned int handletype, const SQLHANDLE& handle)
{
    SQLWCHAR sqlstate[1024];
    SQLWCHAR message[1024];
    if (SQL_SUCCESS == SQLGetDiagRec(handletype, handle, 1, sqlstate, NULL, message, 1024, NULL))
        cout << "Message: " << message << "\nSQLSTATE: " << sqlstate << endl;
}

int main()
{
    SQLHANDLE sqlenvhandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlconnectionhandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlstatementhandle;
    SQLRETURN retcode;

    do
    {
        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlenvhandle))
            break;

        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlenvhandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0))
            break;

        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlenvhandle, &sqlconnectionhandle))
            break;

        SQLWCHAR retconstring[1024];
        /*switch (SQLDriverConnect(sqlconnectionhandle, NULL,
            L"Driver={ODBC Driver 10 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:xyz.database.windows.net;Database=ProjectLIT;UID=auser;PWD=zzzzz;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;",
            SQL_NTS, retconstring, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT)*/
        switch (SQLDriverConnect(sqlconnectionhandle, NULL,
            L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=xyz.database.windows.net,1433;DATABASE=ProjectLIT;UID=auser;PWD=zzzzz;",
            SQL_NTS, retconstring, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT))
        {
        case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
            show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
            break;
        case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
        case SQL_ERROR:
            show_error(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlconnectionhandle);
            retcode = -1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (retcode == -1)
            break;

        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlconnectionhandle, &sqlstatementhandle))
            break;

        //if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlstatementhandle, L"SELECT * FROM Emploees_Res", SQL_NTS))
        if (SQL_SUCCESS != SQLExecDirect(sqlstatementhandle, L"SELECT [Internal Email ID] FROM [Emploees_Res] WHERE [Office Acc]=63", SQL_NTS))
        {
            show_error(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlstatementhandle);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            char name[64];

            while (SQLFetch(sqlstatementhandle) == SQL_SUCCESS)
            {
                SQLGetData(sqlstatementhandle, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, name, 64, NULL);
                cout << name;
            }
        }
    } while (FALSE);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlenvhandle);

}
```

I thought the error might be in connection string.

Can anyone please advise where the correction is needed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is lacking context, but one thing for sure is that these `(SQLWCHAR*)` casts have no chance to work the way you expect. Use `L"wide string literals"` instead.

Comment: I have used wide string Liteerals, but still getting error, can you please advice where in need correction

Comment: Code is still not complete, and you didn't post the error message. It's easy enough to copy/paste and might be all it takes for someone to diagnose your issue even without a Microsoft toolchain at hand.

Comment: Sorry, When I add the Completed code, its not getting Saved, Any how now I have added complete Code, Could anyone please advice, where I need the changes..

Comment: You should post errors as text, not images. Text is searchable for others having/solving the same problem; images are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to all,

Finally got the solution, as said by **quentin** used L wide string Literals

Below is the exact Connection string

switch (SQLDriverConnect(sqlconnectionhandle, NULL,
                    L"DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=tcp:xyz.database.windows.net,1433;DATABASE=ProjectLIT;UID=auser;PWD=zzzzzz;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;",
                    SQL_NTS, retconstring, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT))